# Comparing two collections with IEquatable while using only LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5, ienumerable, iequatable

This question is for educational purposes only and I can solve it easily by using `for` loop that returns `false` on first mismatch.

I am implementing `IEquatable<CustomerFeedbackViewModel>` on `CustomerFeedbackViewModel` which has a collection of `QuestionViewModel` that I need to compare element by element.

```
public class CustomerFeedbackViewModel 
{
    public List<QuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }

    public string PageName { get; set; }

    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

when implementing `Equals` instead of using `for` loop I mentioned above I wanted to use `TrueForAll` method it would look something like below.

```
public bool Equals(CustomerFeedbackViewModel other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Questions.TrueForAll((o,i) => o.Equals(other.Questions.ElementAt(i))) && string.Equals(PageName, other.PageName) && string.Equals(SessionId, other.SessionId);
    }
```

Ofc `TrueForAll` does not have index and above will never fly.

**How could I go around implementing comparison of two lists without using `for` loop but instead using linq 'oneliner'?**

Comment: I think you'd want `List1.SequenceEqual(List2.Take(List1.Count))` to compare all elements in List1 with the corresponding elements in List2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of comparing each question at all indexes you should use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
return string.Equals(PageName, other.PageName) 
    && string.Equals(SessionId, other.SessionId) 
    && Questions.SequenceEqual(other.Questions);
```

If you don't override `Equals` + `GethashCode` in `QuestionViewModel` you can provide a custom [`IEqualityComparer<QuestionViewModel>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass that to the `SequenceEqual` overload or implement `IEquatable<QuestionViewModel>`.

Comment: Hi Tim, there literally no way for there to be a better solution, thanks :) I just realized that I will go on rewrite spree to change all the places where I have used for loop.

Comment: If not using .NET Core, it might be worth testing that the two sequences have the same count and short-cut to false otherwise. .NET Core will short-cut if the sequences both implement `ICollection<T>` and have different counts, but other frameworks' versions of `SequenceEqual` will not.